# How to find ip address of Iphone connected to Mac

Tags: ios, network, bonjour

I want to find IP Address of Iphone which is connected through usb to my Mac.

Kindly note that Mac and Iphone are on different networks.

I used ideviceinfo which gives me the Iphone MAC address. I did not have any luck finding IP address from MAC address either.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a WiFi network, go to the **Settings** app, then **Wi-Fi**.  On the Wi-Fi screen, touch the circled-i to the right of your connected network, and the IP of your phone will be displayed along with some other network information.

Comment: Yes i know that, but that does not solve my problem. I want to get IP address of IPhone **from Mac machine**